# using keyword on nested class to get enum in c++

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces, nested

I was playing around with `using` keyword, but with no success. How can I accomplish something similar to the example shown below?

Example:

```
class A
{
public:
   void foo();
private:
   class B 
   {
   public:
       enum num_e {one,two,three};
   };
};

void A::foo()
{
    //I don't want write like this:
    B::num_e en = B::one; 

    //I want write like this:
    num_e en = one;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the enumeration in a private section of class A and it will be visible to A and B.

Comment: it's not beautiful solution :), in context of my task enum relates to B, but not to A

Comment: B is a private nested class, hence there is nothing ugly putting the enumeration right before B.

Comment: I have many nested classes - and if i put all nested enums to A it will looks like garbage.